# Word Order run faster

Tags: python, list

I have the next code:

```
`#!/bin/python3
from collections import Counter
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Introduce the number of words
    number = int(input ())
    words = []

    for _ in range (number):
        #Introduce Words
        words.append(input().strip())

    for text in words:
        cnt = Counter ()
        for word in words:
            cnt[word] += 1

    print (len (cnt))
    print (*list (cnt.values()), sep = " ")*`
```

First input is for the numbers of words in a list
The next input are the number of words of the first input.
Input example is:

```
4 #Number of words
asd
ert
sdf
asd
```

The output is:

```
3 #(Different words in the list)
2 1 1 #(Number of the same words in the list)
```

The code works fine, but the problem is when I have 100 000 words, it takes to much time, Can you help me to run faster?

Comment: Why do you have two loops over `words`?  With 100,000 words, you are creating and populating 100,000 `Counter`s, all of them identical, and throwing away the first 99,999 of them.

Comment: Where you have `for text in words:`, delete that line, and unindent the next three lines.  That turns an N*N operation into an O(N).

Comment: My problem was that I didn't understand very well the Counter().

Answer (score 0):

Your code **Time Complexity** is `O(N^2)` reason. you have nested loops to iterate through all possible pairs of words

**Time Complexity: `O(N)` Space Complexity: `O(N)`**

**Code:**

```
from collections import Counter
lis=[]
n=int(input("Enter: "))
for i in range(n):
    lis.append(input())

count=Counter(lis)
print(len(count))
print(*list(count.values()),sep=" ")
```

**Output:**

```
Enter: 4
asd
ert
sdf
asd
3
2 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks. It is very easy your answer, for me was a little difficult to resolve because I didn't understand very well Counter(), now I understand it.